# 125 amp sub panel off of 200 amp main panel 200ft away

Tags: electrical

What size Aluminum wire do I need? 2/0 AWG will run the load but need to confirm the voltage drop for distance.

Comment: What is the anticipated actual load?

Comment: Anything wrong with the [Southwire Voltage Drop Calculator](https://www.southwire.com/calculator-vdrop)?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Southwire's calculator is great. But key first is to find out: (a) Is this a 125A panel that will be maxed out (125A * .8 = 100A continuous) or much less (125A panel being used to get lots of spaces or other features but actual load 50A or 60A or whatever) and (b) Are the loads primarily 240V (water heater, HVAC, big tools, etc.) or 120V? Both can make a big difference. Might be perfectly fine with cheap 2 AWG AL or might need much bigger wire.

Comment: I don't see where load matters, just size. If you're putting in a 125 amp main on the subpanel you need to wire it as if 125 amps will be used.

Comment: @KMJ   THat's not correct. The breaker in the main panel needs to match the WIRE/CABLE going to the sub panel. The OP could run 12 ga to the sub as long as it's protected by a 20 amp breaker. Not that that's a good idea, just saying.   At any rate, the OP needs to do a load calculation:  what is the sub panel feeding? MJ grow lights? a shop with machinery? How much power will be used at the same time?   That will determine wire size/breaker size.

Comment: Fair point, I figured when they said 125 sub they were planning to feed it with 125. You're absolutely right, if they are feeding with, say, 60A they can get away with 2AWG aluminum. So asker, what size breaker are you feeding with?

Comment: @George the breaker on the main must be <= the cable to be used, e.g. 60A breaker is fine on 90A feeder.   However the "round up" rule says if you have a feeder such as #6NM with 55A rating, but 55A is not a standard breaker size, you can "round up" to 60A - you just can't plan to use the extra 5A.

Comment: This will be 125 amp breaker to feed less than 100 continuous amps.

Answer (score 3):

At 200' you're *barely* at the point where I even bother to do a Load Calculation.   1/0 aluminum is rated for 120A and so you're just a little too far to use that.  So you should be fine at 2/0 aluminum.

I'm assuming when you say "125A subpanel" you mean "my subpanel's Load Calculation shows I have 100A of actual loads, and the 125% derate forces me to 125A".

If you're not thinking about loads and are just grabbing a random subpanel off a shelf at the store, and it happens to say "125A bus limit", then you're not obliged to deliver 125A feeder to it.  But feel free if you want to.

Remember you do *two* Load Calculations. One for the subpanel to assure you are not overloading the subpanel or feeder.  The second for *the entire service* which includes all loads in all panels, to assure the service is not being overloaded.

If this is for EV charging, ask about that - we can steer you clear of many costly novice errors due to misconceptions in the EV community.